Account::try_from is not working because of the lifetime issue
I am trying to create an instruction where I decide which Account struct should be used based on an argument. I am accepting UncheckedAccount and trying to convert it to Account with PriceUpdateV2 struct data.
The error on Account::<PriceUpdateV2>::try_from says: "explicit lifetime required in the type of ctx"
if I replace '_ with 'info as analizer siggests it shows another error on #[program] like this:  "__accounts does not live long enough
borrowed value does not live long enough"
here is the code:
#[program]
pub mod oracle {
  use pyth_solana_receiver_sdk::price_update::PriceUpdateV2;

use super::*;

  pub fn record_price_test<'info>(
    ctx: Context<'_, '_, '_, 'info, Initialize<'info>>, 
    data_source_name: String, 
    asset_id: String, 
    timestamp: i64) -> Result<()> {

    let account: Account<'_, PriceUpdateV2> = Account::<PriceUpdateV2>::try_from(&ctx.accounts.oracle_account).expect("Some error");

    Ok(())
  }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
  pub oracle_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
}


I'm not sure here but maybe you may try to work with data and directly loading PriceUpdateV2?
Similar to this
let data = &mut (*ctx.accounts.oracle_account.data).borrow_mut();
let account = PriceUpdateV2::try_from_slice(&data).unwrap();


let data = ctx.accounts.oracle_account.try_borrow_mut_data()?;
let account = PriceUpdateV2::try_deserialize(&mut data.as_ref()).expect("Error deserializing account data");
Did this eventually, thanks for the reply.
